# Can you make a function parameter in C point to a variable?

Tags: c, function, variables, parameters

I'm just learning C, however I have played around with Ruby a lot in the past, and one thing you could do there was create a function that would allow you to pass in variable that could then be redefined in that function.  In C however it appears that the function does not look at the variable, but instead what is stored in that variable.  For example:

```
void add(int a, int b, int c);

int main(void)
{
    int num1 = 1, num2 = 1, num3;

    add(num1, num2, num3);
    printf("%d", num3);

}

void add(int a, int b, int c)
{
    c = a + b;
}
```

Simply returns an error stating that the variable num3 in undefined.  So my question is, am I simply doing this incorrectly due to my lack of knowledge, and if so what is the correct way, or is this simply impossible in the C language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C passes variables by value.  If you printed `c` in the function after the addition, it would have the value 2.  However, this does nothing to the variable in `main` (which is uninitialized).  To change that, you'd have to pass it by address:

```
void add(int a, int b, int *c)
{
    *c = a + b;
}
```

and:

```
add(num1, num2, &num3);
```

Alternatively, you could have the function return the new value:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

num3 = add(num1, num2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but arguments in C are passed by value.  Always.  You can get what you want by using indirection, i.e., pass a pointer;

```
void add(int a, int b, int *sum)
{
    if (!sum)
        // handle error
    *sum = a + b;
}

// calling this function...
add(a, b, &c);
```

You can always add a level of indirection.  if you need to set a `whatever*` inside of a function, then you pass a `whatever**`.  Of course, you can always mutate what a pointer *refers to* without adding indirection because you only need the address.

```
void foo(whatever *w) 
{
    // this works, because dereferencing the 
    // pointer gets you to the same address in 
    // memory that the original refers to
    w->something = something_else;

    // this does not work as you may expect 
    // because you are mutating the local copy
    w = caller_will_never_see;
}
```

---

Of course, I think this version is better, but it's you're call:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

No need for handling null pointers and you can call it more naturally:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = add(a, b);
```